# All kubernetes pods configuration don't refresh on calling actuator refresh endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

I have multiple pods for the same microservices in a kubernetes cluster. Each pod has exactly one instance of the microservice. All these pods are behind a network load balancer. 
I hit the LB with /refresh end point, and this refreshed only config for the container of the pod that it load balanced.
Is there a way to refresh configs for containers of all pods for this microservice by not individually call each containers?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way in Kubernetes to do this without making a request to all endpoints individually. You can get all endpoint addresses from the service with `kubectl get endpoints <service-name>`.

See also [Kubenetes: Is it possible to hit multiple pods with a single request in Kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612412/kubenetes-is-it-possible-to-hit-multiple-pods-with-a-single-request-in-kubernet) and the [referenced GitHub issue #18755](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18755).