# How to send a request to all running pods

Tags: kubernetes

Assuming that the pods have exposed port 80.

How to send a requets to all the running pods, rather than 1.

Since the load balancer would route the traffic to only 1 pod. 
(Note : using HAproxy load balancer here, FYI)

Comment: Would this work for you [Kubenetes: Is it possible to hit multiple pods with a single request in Kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612412/kubenetes-is-it-possible-to-hit-multiple-pods-with-a-single-request-in-kubernet)

Comment: yes .. kind of what i was looking for .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular way, `kubectl exec` only works one container at a time so you will need to call it into a loop if you want to use it on many.

Comment: but how to loop as loadbancer will route it to any pod

Comment: either commands from shell or http request .. i can expose a http port for this