# How to hit Curl on all the running pods on Kubernetes of particular service

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, curl

**Problem Statement** - I need to hit a curl on all the kubernetes pods. Currently if I hit the curl with Cname of the service then it will only go to one of the pod which depends on load balancer.
I need to tweak some configuration so need to hit curl on all the running pods of the service.
We can do it via login into the pods the hit from their but I don't want to do as in future we won't be having access to pods.

I have tried - [Kubenetes: Is it possible to hit multiple pods with a single request in Kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612412/kubenetes-is-it-possible-to-hit-multiple-pods-with-a-single-request-in-kubernet) but no luck here, need to explore more.

My use case - I want to change the log level at runtime without deploying the service and that log level should also apply to new pods that will spons up in the future.

Let me know if you have anything regarding this.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot and/or Spring Cloud? If so call the refresh endpoint after changing the configuration (when done in a cluster there should be a queue to listen to for all pods which triggers the refresh).

Comment: If I call the refresh endpoint then also request will go to one of the pods only and hence config will get updated for one pod only.
Can you help me with how I can set up a queue that listens to the request ?

Comment: That is explained in the Spring Cloud Config guide.